# Output the index of the event in the solution when using VectorContinuousCallback in Julia/DifferentialEquations

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

I have a dynamical system for which many events could occur. I want to terminate the integration of the trajectory on an event, but I also want to known which event has been activated.

The workaround I found is to use a global variable to save the event index in the `affect!` function. Here is a modified version of the [bouncing ball example](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/features/callback_functions.html#VectorContinuousCallback-Example-1):

```
using DifferentialEquations

function f(du,u,p,t)
  du[1] = u[2]
  du[2] = -p
  du[3] = u[4]
  du[4] = 0.0
end

function condition(out,u,t,integrator) # Event when event_f(u,t) == 0
  out[1] = u[1]
  out[2] = (u[3] - 10.0)u[3]
end

event_idx = [0, ]  # global variable
function affect!(integrator, idx)
    event_idx[1] = idx
    terminate!(integrator)
end

cb = VectorContinuousCallback(condition,affect!,2)

u0 = [50.0,0.0,0.0,2.0]
tspan = (0.0,15.0)
p = 9.8
prob = ODEProblem(f,u0,tspan,p)
sol = solve(prob,Tsit5(),callback=cb,dt=1e-3,adaptive=false)
println(sol.retcode)
println(event_idx) # [1]
```

Is there a better solution for doing this?

Comment: You can also use `integrator.p` as a cache, and change around that value, and use `sol.prob.p` at the end. But yeah, this or a `Ref` is a fine way to do it.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Thanks! I didn't know I could access `sol.prob.p` (and for differentialequations.jl, it's the reason I am trying to move to Julia)

Answer (score 0):

You can use integrator.p as a cache, and change around that value, and use sol.prob.p at the end. But yeah, this or a Ref is a fine way to do it.